# Hypothesis testing with time autocorrelated data

Tags: r, regression, time-series, hypothesis-testing, mixed-model

I have a dataset such as the following:

```
  Datetime            Box    DV_T  IV_T
1 2019-12-25 14:00:00 5.4    37.4  30.7
2 2019-12-25 14:01:00 5.4    37.2  30.8
3 2019-12-25 14:02:00 5.4    37.1  30.8
4 2019-12-25 14:03:00 5.4    37.8  30.9
5 2019-12-25 14:04:00 5.4    38.4  30.9
6 2019-12-25 14:05:00 5.4    38.5  31.0
```

where `IV_T` is the ambient temperature (independent variable) and `DV_T` is the temperature recorded by a sensor inside a `Box` (respectively dependent variable and random categorical variable). Temperatures were logged once a minute over a few days (in variable `Datetime`)

I want to test
$H_{0}$: `IV_T` does not explain `DV_T`
$H_{1}$: `IV_T` does explain `DV_T`

so, pretty standard stuff. If my observations were independent I would run `lmer(DV_T ~ IV_T + (1|Box))` and extract p-values using `Anova()` from the `car` package.

However, I'm unsure how to account for the autocorrelation in my dataset. I'd appreciate any help with either theory or code in R.

Comment: I think you should consider ARIMAX models, see https://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/arimax/, as changes in ambient temperature is not going to have an immediate effect on the temperature inside the box (because of the physics of heat flow).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does get complicated. One option could be to use the `lme` function from the `nlme` package, which allows the inclusion of an autocorrelation structure to model time (or space) correlations.

Example model for your data below. I've used `corAR1(form=~1|Box)`, representing 1) an autocorrelation structure of order 1, 2) the order of the observations in the data as a covariate, 3) the correlation structure is assumed to apply only to observations within the same grouping level.

```
library(nlme)
mod=lme(
  DV_T~IV_T,
  random=~1|Box,
  correlation=corAR1(form=~1|Box),
  data=df
)

Linear mixed-effects model fit by REML
  Data: df 
  Log-restricted-likelihood: -0.6696385
  Fixed: DV_T ~ IV_T 
(Intercept)        IV_T 
 -31.479769    2.248871 

Random effects:
 Formula: ~1 | Box
        (Intercept) Residual
StdDev:     1.09404 1.004925

Correlation Structure: AR(1)
 Formula: ~1 | Box 
 Parameter estimate(s):
      Phi 
0.9045141 
Number of Observations: 6
Number of Groups: 1
```